# Calculate maximum speed for a car in game

Tags: physics

I'm trying to write a program that will simulate driving a car along a given route. I would like to ask if there is a fairly simple way to calculate the optimal speed/velocity for each section of the route, assuming that we know parameters such as the weight of the car, acceleration, the angle at which the car moves, the maximum speed of the vehicle, power.
Let's assume that it can travel at a maximum speed of 300km/h (83m/s), weighs is 750kg, acceleration is 0–100 km/h in 2 sec and power 1000 KM.

Can you tell what calculations should be made to calculate the maximum speed for such a vehicle when passing a 25-degree turn, when should he start braking, when start to accelerate?
Is any more data needed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Artificial intelligence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r428O_CMcpI) should get you pretty close.

Comment: I would like to calculate this :) not create AI

Answer (score 0):

Of course a 25-degree curve means a central angle of 25 degrees but also a deflection angle of 25 degrees at the (PI) intersection of the straight tangents. That's for a tangent curve only. Then with the length of the tangents from begin-of-curve to PI and equally from PI to end-of-curve, a radius can be calculated using highway formulas or otherwise. With a known radius, and lateral G-force of the vehicle, then a mid-curve speed can be calculated with simple skid-pad formulas. But if the car turns-in from a wide line to an apex and then exits to a wide line, a circular curve radius of the curve path must be calculated to use simple skid-pad formulas.

Here is a link:

http://www.kbhscape.com/curve.htm .

Actually, a racing vehicle is slowing-down on the turn-in and speeding-up on the exit but there is a mid-curve speed.